# All cards in Hand the same

Tags: java

im learning java right now in secondary school and having a problem with my code. When create a hand using a string all Card objects in the list have the same rank and suit (in this case; 32) this of course causes a problem because i then try to sort then by rank (regular compareTo of comparing rank then suit). And then try to output the list. I have absolutely no clue why the cards are all created with rank and suit of 32. Im sorry in advance if im posting far too much code or a really big description, first time asking online.

Card class:

```
public class Card implements Comparable<Card>

// 1 - Ace, 2 to 9 , 10 - Ten, 11 - Jack, 12 - Queen, 13 - King
private int rank;
// 1 - Clubs, 2 - Diamonds, 3 - Hearts, 4 - Spades
private int suit;
private boolean isFaceUp;

private static final String SUITS = " CDHS";
private static final String RANKS = " A23456789TJQK";
public static final Comparator<Card> SUIT_ORDER = new SuitOrder();

public Card(int rank, int suit)
{
    this.rank = rank;
    this.suit = suit;
    if (Character.isUpperCase(suit))
        this.isFaceUp = true;

    this.isFaceUp = false;
}

public Card(String givenCard)
{
    // charAt(1) always a letter (suit)
    if (Character.isUpperCase(givenCard.charAt(1)))
    {
        this.isFaceUp = true;
    }
    this.isFaceUp = false;
    // Set both characters to uppercase to match static suits/ranks list
    if (Character.isLetter(givenCard.charAt(0)))
        Character.toUpperCase(givenCard.charAt(0));
    Character.toUpperCase(givenCard.charAt(1));
    // now set rank/suit of this card object
    // dont call other card constructor, use this one
    //this.rank = 22;
    //this.suit = 3;
    this.rank = RANKS.indexOf(givenCard.charAt(0));
    this.suit = SUITS.indexOf(givenCard.charAt(1));
}

public void flip()
{
    this.isFaceUp = true;
}

public boolean isFaceUp()
{
    return this.isFaceUp;
}

public int compareTo(Card otherCard)
{
    if (this.rank != otherCard.rank)
        return this.rank - otherCard.rank;

    return otherCard.suit - this.suit;
}

public static class SuitOrder implements Comparator<Card>
{
    public int compare(Card first, Card second)
    {
        if (first.suit != second.suit)
            return second.suit - first.suit;

        return second.rank - first.rank;
    }
}

public int getValue()
{
    // 1-10, face cards value 11/12/13
    return this.rank;
}

public boolean isAce()
{
    if (this.rank == 1)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

public String toString()
{
    return String.format("%c%c", RANKS.charAt(rank), SUITS.charAt(suit));
}
```

Hand class:

```
public class Hand

private ArrayList<Card> hand;

public Hand()
{
    // empty hand
    hand = new ArrayList<Card>();
}

public Hand(String str)
{
    Scanner handStr = new Scanner(str);
    // Initialize array list
    hand = new ArrayList<Card>(str.length() / 3 + 1);
    while (handStr.hasNext())
    {
        hand.add(new Card(handStr.next()));
    }
    handStr.close();
}

public int getValue()
{
    int value = 0;
    for (int count = 0; count < hand.size(); count++)
    {
        value += (hand.get(count)).getValue();
        // if ace add 10
    }
    // if over 21, keep track of aces, change to 1
    return value;
}

public boolean isBlackJack()
{
    return (hand.size() == 2 && getValue() == 21);
}

public void addCard(Card card)
{
    hand.add(card);
}

public void sortByRank()
{
    Collections.sort(hand);
}

public void sortBySuit()
{
    Collections.sort(hand, Card.SUIT_ORDER);
}

public void clear()
{
    hand.clear();
}

public int cardsLeft()
{
    return hand.size();
}

public String toString()
{
    return hand.toString();
}
```

Deck class:

```
public class Deck

private Card[] deck;
int topCard;

public Deck(int noOfDecks)
{
    topCard = 0;
    deck = new Card[52 * noOfDecks];
    for (int decks = 0; decks < noOfDecks; decks++)
    {
        for (int suit = 1; suit < 5; suit++)
        {
            for (int rank = 1; rank < 14; rank++)
            {
                deck[topCard] = (new Card(rank, suit));
                topCard++;
            }
        }
    }
}

public Deck()
{
    // calls other deck constructor but with only one deck
    this(1);
}

public void shuffle()
{
    // double check
    // zero based arrays
    for (int i = 0; i < deck.length - 1; i++)
    {
        int random = (int) (Math.random() * (deck.length - 1));
        Card temp = deck[i];
        deck[i] = deck[random];
        deck[random] = temp;
    }
    // check to make sure all cards are face down after shuffle
    for (int cards = 0; cards < deck.length - 1; cards++)
    {
        if (deck[cards].isFaceUp() == true)
            deck[cards].flip();
    }
    // re-set topCard to deck length
    topCard = deck.length - 1;
}

public Card dealCard()
{
    // no cards left in deck
    if (topCard == 0)
        return null;

    topCard--;
    return deck[topCard];
}

public int cardsLeft()
{
    return topCard;
}

public String toString()
{
    // show only non-dealt cards
    StringBuilder deckDisplay = new StringBuilder((deck.length - 1) * 2);
    for (int index = 0; index < topCard; index++)
    {
        deckDisplay.append(deck[index].toString());
        deckDisplay.append(" ");
    }
    return deckDisplay.toString();
}
```

Last but not least the test code that breaks it all:

```
// Make a second Hand from the Cards in a String
    Hand secondHand = new Hand("9H 9C 6D KH JS 5C AD 7S 8S JH 6C 8H TD " +
                               "3C 3D 6H AH QD 2S 9S AC 8D TC 5D 7D QH " +
                               "4D QC QS 3H 6S KD KS TS 7H 7C 4C 9D JC " +
                               "AS 8C KC 2C 4S 2H TH 5S 2D 3S 5H 4H JD");
    secondHand.sortByRank();
    System.out.println(secondHand);
```

Comment: You have `this.rank = 22;` in one of your constructors. You're saying "if you make a new card and pass in a string, make the rank 22 everytime." That's almost surely not what you want.

Comment: There's also a this.suit=3 directly under the this.rank=22 line.

Comment: sorry, the commented out code below it was supposed to be the code, the static values i put to test if it would change from making every card 32 rank, 32 suit, to the values i set and it did not, so im not sure whats happening.

Answer (score 1):

The `Card` constructor is hard-coded with

```
this.rank = 22;
this.suit = 3;
```

So you always get the same card. You need to set rank and suit based on the passed in `givenCard`. Also, `Character` does not modify in place. I think you wanted something like

```
this.rank = Character.toUpperCase(givenCard.charAt(0));
this.suit = Character.toUpperCase(givenCard.charAt(1));
```

Comment: edited code, the commented out code below it is now uncommented and should have been the code used for the constructor, the static values were test values.

Comment: @ShadowBlade What happened next?

Comment: @CBredlow literally nothing changed and i dont know why.
http://gyazo.com/47bc2f219f50dd69cc6880f6b4ee58a5
Heres a picture of the error stack i think its called, the index is still 32 and out of range when trying to toString (meaning suit/rank is still 32..)

Comment: @ShadowBlade rank and suit are 0. You didn't set those variables.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch added this code
this.rank = RANKS.indexOf(givenCard.charAt(0));
this.suit = SUITS.indexOf(givenCard.charAt(1));

Answer (score 0):

The reason you have the rank as 32, is that in your Card constructor, you set the suit to be 3.  You also set the rank to 22, and pull the first character, so you read that as 2.  If you remove those lines, it should correct itself.

Comment: edited code, the commented out code below it is now uncommented and should have been the code used for the constructor, the static values were test values.

Answer (score 0):

Talked to my teacher today, turns out i fixed my code somewhere along the way but never cleaned my projects, so my .class file was never updated with the new code and thats why i couldnt see any changes. But i did fix it from where i had it before, i think it was the added indexOf in the card constructor.